# Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Why am I getting this error for such a simple relationship query?

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::country()
```

I just want to get a list of lookup values from my lookup table called `pc_country`. I have even included the namespaces!

Controller;

```
$tableName = $postcode_tablename->dataset; //eg 201502_postcode

$country = PostcodeExtract::fromTable($tableName)
                        ->country() //this is generating the error!
                        ->distinct()
                        ->select('description')
                        ->get();

var_dump($country);
exit;
```

Country Model;

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model {

  protected $connection = 'postcodes';

  public $table = 'pc_country';

  protected $fillable = ['description', 'country_id', 'code'];

  public function postcodeExtract()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostcodeExtract');
  }
}
```

PostCode Extract Model;

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PostcodeExtract extends Model {

protected $connection = 'postcodes';

protected $fillable = ['country'];

  public function scopeFromTable($query, $tableName) 
  {
    return $query->from($tableName);
  }

  public function country()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Country');
  }
}
```

My `201502_postcode` table has a `country_id` and my `pc_country` table has a `id` field for it to do the lookup on. Is that correct? I don't see the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You used fromTable method(scope) it returns eloquent query builder so your relations wont be available. Consider same code without calling that method.

If you want to change table of model create an instance and then call setTable method on the created instance then use your instance to query

```
$instance = new PostCodeExtract();
$instance->setTable ("table");
$country = $instance->country()->........
```

Sorry im on mobile couldn't provide good example code but you can achieve it with this method